# How reputable is the online journal scientific.net: Materials Science and Engineering

Tags: journals

How reputable is the online journal "Scientific.Net: Materials Science and Engineering"

http://www.scientific.net/

Comment: Could someone point me to the duplicate question and answers? Searching for "scientific.net" produces no results.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.  Scientific.Net: Materials Science and Engineering is a journal publisher.

It publishes, for example: http://www.scientific.net/MSF *Materials Science Forum* ISSN 1662-9752